# List<t> to array (in separate class)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, .net-3.5

Below is the basic setup of my program thus far. 2 classes. One to keep track of the OrderInfo and the other to do the WebRequest processes and gather the information.

I know that 
                `order.FullCashValues = Details.ToArray();` will put all the values of my `Details` List into the `FullCashValues` object[]. But i just want the first 6 items to go into that object and the rest of the objects in the `Details` list to go into the `AssessedValues` object[].

Any help?

```
    Public Class OrderInfo
    {
    public object[] FullCashValues {get;set;}
    public object[] AssessedValues {get;set;}
    }

Public Class WebRequests
{
    public static List<List<object>> Main_Process(OrderInfo order)
    {
    //returns a list of values taken from the url
    List<object> Details = DetailsPage(url1, ParcelNumber);

    //Details[0] through Details[5] should go into 
    //FullCashValues

    //Details[6] through Details[11] should go into
    //AssessedValues
    }
    }
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you insist on using `List<object>` and `object[]`? Unless your arrays/lists *really do* contain objects of different types, you should have them be of a particular type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to split the list (both methods are available in .NET 3.5).

```
FullCashValues = Details.Take(6).ToArray();
AssessedValues = Details.Skip(6).ToArray();
```